# Segmentation fault when trying to createcustomchannel() from client

Tags: c++, grpc

I have written in an application in which I am trying to communicate with the server by creating custom channel as follows,

```
grpc::ChannelArguments ca;
ca.SetMaxReceiveMessageSize(-1);
std::shared_ptr\<grpc::Channel\> channel = grpc::CreateCustomChannel(ip, grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials(), ca);
```

As soon as application is started if I try to start the communication by creating instance I am seeing the segmentation fault in line while calling

CreateCustomChannel()

like below

```
*grpc_core::ScopedTimeCache::Now - 7ff9e80baba0)  
grpc_core::Timestamp::Now - 7ff9e802cbf0)  
grpc_core::channelz::ChannelTrace::ChannelTrace - 7ff9e8416340)  
grpc_core::channelz::ChannelNode::ChannelNode - 7ff9e817b310)  
grpc_core::MakeRefCounted\<grpc_core::channelz::ChannelNode,std::basic_string\<char,std::char_traits\    <char\>,std::allocator\<char\> \> &,unsigned \__int64 const &,bool const &\> - 7ff9e815c0c0)  
grpc_core::Channel::Create - 7ff9e8158df0)  
grpc_core::\`anonymous namespace'::CreateChannel - 7ff9e8541af0)  
grpc_channel_create - 7ff9e8540330)  
grpc::\`anonymous namespace'::InsecureChannelCredentialsImpl::CreateChannelWithInterceptors - 7ff9e8afedc0)  
grpc::\`anonymous namespace'::InsecureChannelCredentialsImpl::CreateChannelImpl - 7ff9e8afec80)  
grpc::CreateCustomChannel - 7ff9e8afcbe0)*
```

But if I wait for 2 min and try to connect it connecting also it is working as expected. I am not getting what is the issue. Please guide me on this. Am i missing any thing in settings or any compilation flags?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

I tried to create custom channel but seeing crash saying grpc::`anonymous namespace'::InsecureChannelCredentialsImpl::CreateChannelImpl. I am trying to catch the exception also but not able to catch also.
Need to know why it is crashing as soon as i try to connect after the application starts.
Does not crash if I wait for 2 min after the app is up and connect it works as expected.

Comment: Can you try this example of CreateCustomChannel and see if you have the same issue? https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/db9ca10b351da70cd34359f8ea5ea00cbb4ffc1a/examples/cpp/compression/greeter_client.cc